# Alamofire's Reachability and compatibility with IPv6

Tags: swift, alamofire, ipv6, reachability

I'm using NetworkReachabilityManager and my app got rejected by Apple due IPv6 issues. I think it's the way I used the reachability.

Here is an example of my code:

```
let reachabilityManager = NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "https://www.apple.com/")!

if reachabilityManager.isReachable {
        
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters,  encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                callback(json)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
            
        }
        
    } else {
        print("Internet not available")
    }
```

What is the right way to use Alamofire's Reachability?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the rejection message from apple:

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 10.3.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review."

Comment: If I had to guess... you shouldn't use `www.apple.com` with reachability, but the host of whatever URL you call through Alamofire.  What were the IPv6 issues that Apple pointed at?

Comment: Please can you post the exact reason Apple gave for rejection?

Comment: @ScottThompson I don't think  www.apple.com  is the problem. Please check the update of the question.

Comment: @AshleyMills Please check the update

Comment: Did you test this on an IPv6-only network?

Comment: @RonMaupin I tired to, but I couldn't get the computer connect to an IPv6 network. I followed [this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html) but no luck

Comment: If you can't test properly, then you will not get it to pass Apple's tests. You must get it to work on an IPv6-only network because that is how Apple tests it.